# Xcode - is adhoc build debug or release?

Tags: xcode

I have flag in `other swift flags` for debug so I can have macro in code for `DEBUG`. Will it trigger in ad-hoc ? How will work ad-hoc build ? As debug or release ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default is release but you can change this in the scheme editor

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Watch your scheme details to see which configuration is used for the `Archive` stage (as I assume you're making the Ad-Hoc build from the archived product).

In the menu bar, navigate to `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme…` and switch to the one you're currently building if needed.